# Maven - create archetype which uses mojo for source generation

Tags: maven, code-generation, maven-archetype

I have a MOJO which uses a configuration XML file and generates Java source files:

- The input configuration file is put `\src\main\<name of mojo>\`, belonging to the project which uses the MOJO.
- The output generated source files are put in the directory `target\generated-sources\<name of mojo>\`, belonging to the project which uses the MOJO.

Now I want to create (not use!) an archetype which uses the MOJO to generate its source files. This means that:

1. The end-user of the archetype must be able to pass the configuration to the archetype.
2. The archetype must be able to execute the MOJO to generate the source files.

Is this possible? To summarize, the flow is:

1) The end-user uses archetype to create a Maven project; end-user provides configuration file.

2) The archetype accepts the configuration file and uses the MOJO to generate the sources. The pom.xml and other resources are built-in into the archetype.

3) The end-user gets a Maven project, which he probably will treat as read-only.

In other words, the outcome of the archetype depends on the provided input (configuration).

Comment: Your question in unclear. What do you mean by "archetype"? A [Maven archetype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) helps to create an entire project from a template, so I don't see the connection with a plugin MOJO. It sounds like you just need to add a configuration to the plugin declaration when you are using it.

Comment: @Tunaki An archetype indeed creates a project. My question boils down to: is it possible to use a MOJO during that creation/generation, such that the MOJO is responsible for the creation/generation of a subset of the project source files? In addition, the behaviour of the MOJO depends on a provided configuration file.

Comment: I see. Well, I don't think it is possible but maybe someone here will have an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me it is not possible to do what you are looking for. Instead 
I propose you to look at partial achetype which allows to execute mvn archetype:generate on existing maven project.

In order to explain what it does. Imagine that you are working on a maven project and you want to apply a partial archetype on it. This partial archetype contains a pom.xml with some dependencies and a directory structure which contains some files.

To apply this partial archetype you run the command mvn archetype:generate inside your maven project.

Once applied both pom.xml files are merged and files and directory structure as well.

Technically a partial archetype is a regular archetype that contains a partial attribute to true inside its archetype descriptor file.

```
<archetype-descriptor 
    xmlns="..." 
    xsi:schemaLocation="..." 
    name="MyProject" 
    partial="true">
...
</archetype-descriptor>
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html

Comment: How does the partial archetype calls the MOJO to generate the sources and inject it into the target project?

Comment: Unfortunately the partial archetype can't call the MOJO. I wanted to point out a different approach to your problem. I know that does not solve exactly your question but I have not enough reputation to give you a simple comment to expose this clue. I think you should forget to give an XML file to the end user. You should give a partial archetype to your end user instead. It means you should create (if it possible) the same number of partial archetypes as possible combination of your XML file.

Comment: Thanks. In my situation it is not possible to create all the (partial) archetypes in advance, as it depends on the configuration, which is limitless. Could you please alter your answer a bit (stating that my question is not possible but you propose another approach), so I can accept it as answer (based on the fact that it is not possible)?

Comment: I edited my answer to allow you to accept it. Thanks.